# error when using mysql connector-j

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I have an error in log after when trying to update the database:

> java.sql.SQLException: Streaming
>   result set null is still active. No
>   statements may be issued when any
>   streaming result sets are open and in
>   use on a given connection. Ensure that
>   you have called .close() on any active
>   streaming result sets before
>   attempting more queries.

I dont understand how a null ResultSet can be active. it looks like the connection is in a wiered state.

Comment: It seems that the solution is to set 
`clobberStreamingResults`  to `true` for the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird?  No.  It looks like you aren't closing your JDBC resources.

You should close Connection, Statement, and ResultSet in a finally block in the scope of the method that created them.

> update the database...result sets are
>   open and in use on a given connection

You cannot reuse a PreparedStatement that's a SELECT at one point and an UPDATE at another without closing in between.

Comment: What I am trying to do is reuse the same statement. when I execute update I dont get back a result set, however sometimes i cant work on the same prepared statement again.

Comment: You should not be doing this.  Create a new prepared statement each time.  Very bad idea.

Comment: even java tutorial say I can do so: `The advantage of using SQL statements that take parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with different values each time you execute it. Examples of this are in the following sections.` http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.htmlwhy not?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you're talking about.  They mean using it in a loop and binding different values, not changing the SQL you're executing.  Big difference.

Comment: I am not changing the sql, only values. I keep a cache of statements by the string and assign different values each time.

Comment: Not according to your earlier comment: "...when I execute update I dont get back a result set, however sometimes i cant work on the same prepared statement..."  A SQL UPDATE does not return a ResultSet.  If you're using the same PreparedStatement for a SELECT and an UPDATE, you must change the SQL.

Comment: I am not changing the sql, I am changing only values marked by '?' in the sql. I am not using the same statement for SELECT and UPDATE. if that what you understand, then it is my mistake.

Comment: I quoted your statement from your question.  If it's not correct, please edit your question.  And it still sounds like you aren't closing your resources properly regardless.  That's the real point.  I can't tell without seeing more of your code.  I'm not sure that I want to.  Please check your code and see if you're closing your resources properly and see if it corrects the problem.